# Create check boxes based on json values

Tags: javascript, html, json, menu

My json look like this

```
[ {
        "type": "quant",
        "name": "horizontalError",
        "prop": [
            0.12,
            12.9
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "categor",
        "name": "magType",
        "prop": [
            "ml",
            "md",
            "mb"
        ]
    }]
```

I have created drop-down menu using the "name" property of each object. Now I am trying to create checkboxes if the type  is categor and slider if the type is quant based on the name the user chooses in the drop down menu

I have come so far but stuck here--

```
d3.json("hashmap.json", function(error,data) {
    if(error) {console.log("error fetching data");}

var hashap = data;



var dropDown = d3.select("#sel").selectAll("option").data(hashap).enter().append("option").text(function(d) { return d.name} ).attr("value",function(d, i) {
         return i;});

    d3.select("#sel").on("change", function() {
          var checkSlider = d3.select("#checkSlider"); // clearing previous checkbox or slider
          if(hashap[this.value].type == "categor") {
            console.log(hashap[this.value].prop.length);
            for(var i =0; i >= hashap[this.value].prop.length; i++){
            checkSlider.append("input").attr("type","checkbox");
            checkSlider.append("label").text(hashap[this.value].prop[i]);
          }
          }
          else {
            checkSlider.append("input").attr("type","range").attr("min", hashap[this.value].prop[0]).attr("max", hashap[this.value].prop[1]);
            checkSlider.append("label").text(hashap[this.value].name);      
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments in the code. Hope this helps

```js
    var hashap = [ {
        "type": "quant",
        "name": "horizontalError",
        "prop": [
            0.12,
            12.9
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "categor",
        "name": "magType",
        "prop": [
            "ml",
            "md",
            "mb"
        ]
    }];
    
   // creating drop down  
 var dropDown = d3.select("#dropdown").selectAll("option").data(hashap).enter().append("option").text(function(d) { return d.name} ).attr("value",function(d, i) {
 return i;});
  
  // adding onchange function 
 d3.select("#dropdown").on("change", function() {
  var checkSlider = d3.select("#checkSlider").html(""); // clearing previous checkbox or slider
  if(hashap[this.value].type == "categor") {
   checkSlider.append("input").attr("type","checkbox");
   checkSlider.append("label").text(hashap[this.value].name);
  }
  else {
   checkSlider.append("input").attr("type","range").attr("min", 0).attr("max", 100);
   checkSlider.append("label").text(hashap[this.value].name);   
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown" ></select>
 <div id="checkSlider"><div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the categorical, I am trying to create the checkboxes for each  prop like 3 check boxes for "ml" , "md" and "mb"

Comment: And in the sliders could you tell me how can i show the label of the values

Comment: I tried doing this for getting checkboxes for all the values but it does not work            if(hashap[this.value].type == "categor") {
                console.log(hashap[this.value].prop.length);
                for(var i =0; i >= hashap[this.value].prop.length; i++){
                checkSlider.append("input").attr("type","checkbox");
                checkSlider.append("label").text(hashap[this.value].prop[i]);
              }

Comment: you need to create checkboxes the same way you created the dropdown. Add data to the element then selectAll(''").enter().appned()..... Hope this helps